# How to set fallback value if validation fails (NestJS, class-validator)

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I have a `Person` class similar to the one described below.
`languages` is an optional property. It may be missing or invalid.
I don't want the post call to fail if `languages` is missing or invalid. Instead, I want to set `languages` to a fallback value, say `["en"]`.

How would I do that?

I've looked into custom validators, but that doesn't seem to fit, since I want to both run all the validations and also change the object if it fails validation.

```
// interface
import { IsString, MinLength, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

class Person {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  public readonly name: string;

  @IsArray()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  @MinLength(1)
  public languages: string[];  // <-- how would I specify a fallback value?
}
```

```
// controller
import { Body, Controller, Post } from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller("signup")
export class SignupController {
   @Post()
   public async submit(@Body() formData: Person) {
      // create the user object and save it to the db
   }

}
```

Comment: What about just having `public languages: string[] = ['en']` in your class definition? So long as you have `transform: true` set for the validation pipe's options this default should be set then

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'm not too familiar with nestjs. Would that value be set even if a value _was_ provided? e.g. `languages: [2]`

I'll check

Comment: If validation fails, you're going to get an error regardless. That's just how the ValidationPipe works. There's no way to tell class-validator "Hey, if you fail, just use this value instead"

Comment: > "Hey, if you fail, just use this value instead"

That's exactly what I've been trying to do

Comment: I know. That's not possible immediately with class-validator. You'd need your own wrapper around it that manages the error handling. A custom pipe would probably be good, but then you won't be able to bind the `ValidationPipe` globally (unless you get really clever about it)

Comment: Maybe make it optional and define a default value on the entity property or database column.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `@Transform` like this

```
import { Transform } from "class-transformer";
import { IsOptional } from 'class-validator';

class Person {
    @IsOptional()
    @Transform(({ value }) => {
        if (/* test for value validity */) {
            return value as string[];
        }
        return fallbackLanguages;
    })
    public languages: string[];
}
```